# Why am I still in jeopardy of have question creation access blocked on Android.SE?

Tags: support, asking-questions, low-quality-posts, post-ban

Essentially, for several months now I seem to have the infamous quote atop the questions writing page that says if I don't pull my act together, I won't be able to ask questions, possibly permanently (depending on how I influence the community). I have read the help page and still cannot work out why, after all this time, I still have this warning.

I have

- Gone over my old questions, and accepted answers where they work
- Provided my own answers where I can
- Voted where necessary

I have no questions with negative scores, and I fail to see why I still have the warning. Any help or detailed explanation please.

***EDIT*** screenshot, just to provide evidence.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: To add, there are no moderator-visible statuses on the account -- as far as I can tell, this message should not be shown to Dan anymore.  I suppose it could be the high proportion of zero-score posts.  SE folks?

Comment: @MatthewRead I'm no expert in how your systems work, but wouldn't the 0 score be neutral? Neither one way or the other?

Comment: I'm not an expert on SE's algorithm here either, just guessing.  They might want more evidence of positive contributions, rather than ones that merely aren't negative.  But again, just conjecture.

Comment: Migrated since it seems like the reason behind this is probably not site-specific.

Comment: Are you accounting for deleted questions? Because the algorithm does.

Comment: Based on the visible posts there are only a couple with downvotes: http://data.stackexchange.com/android/query/521348

Comment: Ah, there are quite a few deleted ones with negative score.  That could be it.

Comment: @MatthewRead yeah, if you see some that could be salvageable you might hand the OP the links to those questions because they might not be able to find those from their profile. Before they undelete they should of course be edited into shape

Comment: [Dan B](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/116168/dan-b) on [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: The issue has cleared. Thanks guys!